# Facebook link preview shows javascript

Tags: facebook

When I post a status update in Facebook to a public page on a website, instead of showing that page, it shows some of the JavaScript.

[image: FaceBook Preview]

What am I doing wrong?  Does the JavaScript need to go into a different place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should explicitly declare what you want using Open Graph tags.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#tags

In this case, you'd need to set the `og:description` meta tag.

Comment: Wow...that's awesome!  Thanks for the prompt response!